# How can I run update on multiple counters faster?

Tags: performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I have an array of counter variables(all initialised to 0). I have k instructions that I need to run on the array. An instruction comprises of incrementing all the values of the array between a start index and an end index(Both inclusive).
For Example:

```
n = 5, k = 2
arr = [0,0,0,0,0]
0,2 - (arr = [1,1,1,0,0])
0,1 - (arr = [2,2,1,0,0])
```

Finally I need to sort this in decreasing order of count value which is easy.
I am facing problem writing code to do this in anything less than O(n^2) time complexity. I have to use two loops.

```
Array counts = [0,0,0,0... n times]
for(Instruction instruction:instructions){
    int start = instruction.start;
    int end = instruction.end;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
        counts.set(i,counts.get(i)+1);
    }
}
```

Is there any way it can be done faster? I am also okay with scraping off the count array and taking any data structure required to achieve this.

Comment: is instructions ordered by somthing?

Comment: Currently random. Can be ordered by your convenience if it makes everything faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `n` be the length of the counter array. We can think of the counter as a sequence of `n` symbols; with `n = 5`, we have

```
. . . . .
```

We can interpret each instruction `(start, end)` as directive to place parentheses around some elements. For example,

1. `(0, 2) => (. . .) . .`
2. `(0, 1) => ((. .) .) . .`

and so on. Your problem is to compute the depth of each element in the parentheses tree.

Here is one way to do it, denoting `(` by `+1`, `)` by `-1` and taking the cumulative sum (in Python).

```
import numpy as np

# counter array with 5 elements
ctr = np.zeros(5+1)
instructions = [(0, 2), (0, 1)]
for s, e in instructions:
  ctr[s] += 1
  ctr[e+1] -= 1

result = ctr.cumsum()[:5]
print(result)
# [2. 2. 1. 0. 0.]
```

Provided constant time array access, this is `O(N + M)` where `N` is the number of instructions and `M` is the counter size.

By the way, sorting can also be done in linear time with radix sort or counting sort, since you are working with integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solutions, i'm sorry, but maybe could help.

Instead of counting them, order `Instructions` by `end`, then when you need a given number `x`, use a binary search to find `x` (if you are using java, there is `Array.binarySearch` which will do it, or if it can't find the searched number, the insertion point), then go backwards and count the element until `end == x`, and go ahead until `x >= start`

```
// instructions sorted by end
// need to find the "occurrence of x"
int occurence = 0;
int pos = instructions.binarySearch();
int i = pos;
while(instructions[i].end == x){
   count++ ;
   i++;
}
i = pos;
while(instructions[i].start <= x){
   if( x <= instructions[i].end)
       count++;
   i++;
}
// count now has the number of occurrence  of x (number of range [start, end] that contains x)
```

I can't see for the moment the actual complexity of this, but try using this, and in case test shows that is slower, i'll delete it

Answer (score 0):

First; convert it into a different form. Specifically, convert the original "increment each item from Start to End" into "add V to each item from Start to End" by finding the overlapping ranges in the original and combining them.

For example, "add 1 to items 1 to 5, then add 1 to items 3 to 8" would become "add 1 to items 1 to 2, then add 2 to items 3 to 5, then add 1 to items 6 to 8".

This means that each element in the array is only ever touched once (and never incremented multiple times).

Second; you might be able to gain a little speed in sorting by introducing an "add zero to items from Start to End" (so that every item in the array is included by one range), sorting the items in each range, then merging the final pre-sorted ranges. My thinking here is that by merging ranges in order of the value added to them and keeping track of "highest value so far", sometimes you'll find that the value added to a range is larger than the "highest value so far" and you can simple concatenate/copy instead of merging (and avoid "if value1 is less than value2" branches).

Of course this would be significantly better if you know the items were sorted before you did anything, or if you know the array was zeroed before you did anything, as that would avoid the need to sort each range before merging.

Note: If the array is always initialized to zero beforehand (and not just initialize to zero once and then updated periodically after that); then "addition" becomes "setting"; there will be no sorting (as all values in a range will be the same) and you will always be able to concatenate instead of merging. In other words, you can generate a whole new array (and not bother initializing the array to zeros beforehand).

Comment: Your solution is very similar to the one @hilberts_drinking_problem shared. But he/she has a more intuitive approach to it.

Comment: @GokuAfrica: My solution was originally written for the "array initialized to zero once and then continually/periodically updated after that" case (where the array contains non-zero values before a group of "instructions" are performed), then modified for the "array is always zeroed beforehand" case. It's the later modifications that made is look like hilberts_drinking_problem's solution.